# How to conditionally add field to JSON using Spring Security persmissions

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I am writing a REST web service and I am using Spring 4 with annotation-based configuration.

I am also using Spring security for HTTP Basic authentication and authorization.

I have an `ItemRestPresentation` class purely used for the presentation layer  whose instances are created in my controller method using instances of another class called Item (the actual domain object). `ItemRestPresentation`instances get converted to the following JSON by my controller method:

**ItemRestPresentation class:**

```
public class ItemRestPresentation {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private boolean canDelete;

   // ... private constructor, public getters and public static factory method to create an ItemRestPresentation instance from an Item instance

}
```

**Generated JSON :**

```
{
    "name" : "item1",
    "description": "Sample item for testing",
    "canDelete" : true
}
```

Is it possible to use Spring Security ACL to set the `canDelete` member of the `ItemRestPresentation` instance to the correct value depending on whether the current user has permission to delete it?

Comment: You could use an `@PostFilter` interceptor on the method returning the resources DTO.

Comment: @chrylis: Wouldn't a "@PostFilter" filter out the whole object if the condition evaluates to false? I want it to be included in the response, but with the "canDelete" field set to false.

Comment: I believe you can modify the object rather than simply reject it. I'm not familiar with the Spring Security domain annotations, but I know there's some way to declaratively decorate methods.